# Must React Router be used if the goal is just to get one or two URL params?

Tags: reactjs

If we use a React app and hope to compare two ways of doing things, by passing in `v=1` or `v=2`

```
www.website.com/foo/?v=1
```

must React Router or some npm package be used to get the value? Does React itself has such a mechanism?  Or else, we can just use `document.location.search` and parse it like in the old days?

Comment: React provides no mechanism for routing by itself. Just use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) with `location.search`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React doesn't have a built-in mechanism for that, but - why not just parse `document.location.search`? If you're not looking for the extra functionality, go ahead and do that. There are easy ways built in to handle such things, for example [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams):

```js
const search = '?my=foo&another=bar' // or document.location.search

const params = new URLSearchParams(search)

console.log(params.get('my'))
console.log(params.get('another'))
```

Stick this into a component directly or into a util function and import it to use in a component.